# I am getting undefined offset:0 Error in Category, subcategory, Subsub category page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.7

I am trying to display category, subcategory, subsubcategory page but i am getting undefined offset:0 error when i am opening any page. Please let me know how i can show my data on a perticular page.

here is my controller GuidePagesController.php

```
<?php
public function categoryGuides(Request $r, $cat, $subcat=NULL,$subsubcat=NULL){
    $guidedata=GuidePages::all();
    if($cat != NULL && $subcat != NULL && $subsubcat != NULL){

        $cat = Category::where('slug',$cat)->get();
        $subcatid = Subcategory::where('slug',$subcat)->get();
        $subsubcatid = SubSubcategory::where('slug',$subsubcat)->get();
        $guides = GuidePages::where(function($q) use($cat, $subcatid, $subsubcatid) {
            $q->where('category_id','=', $cat[0]->id)
                ->where('subcategory_id','=', $subcatid[0]->id) 
                ->where('subsubcategory_id','=', $subsubcatid[0]->id);       
            })->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(8);
        } elseif($cat != NULL && $subcat != NULL) {
            $cat = Category::where('slug',$cat)->get();
            $subcatid = Subcategory::where('slug',$subcat)->get();
            $guides = GuidePages::where(function($q) use($cat, $subcatid){
                $q->where('category_id','=', $cat[0]->id)
                ->where('subcategory_id','=', $subcatid[0]->id);       
            })->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(8);
        } else {
            $cat = Category::where('slug',$cat)->get();
            $guides = GuidePages::where('category_id','=', $cat[0]->id)
                ->orderBy('id','desc')->paginate(10);
        }

    $data=['guidedata'=>$guidedata,'guides'=>$guides,'cat'=>$cat[0]->category_name,];
    return view('guide-pages', $data);
}
```

And here is my route:

```
Route::get("category/{cat}/{subcat?}/{subsubcat?}"
    , ["uses" => "GuidePagesController@categoryGuides"
    , "as" => "category.cat.product"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

After these lines

```
$cat = Category::where('slug',$cat)->get();
$subcatid = Subcategory::where('slug',$subcat)->get();
$subsubcatid = SubSubcategory::where('slug',$subsubcat)->get();
```

you should verify if these $cat, $subcatid and $subsubcatid actually have data or not.
you are getting this offset error because your script is trying to access a value which do not exist.